# Xamarin.Forms 4 URI Route Navigation

Tags: xamarin.forms

I'm trying to get a head start with the pre-releases of Xamarin.Forms 4 and I've hit a road block with some of the Navigation features that have been included. From the Microsoft Docs it states:

> Shell includes a URI-based navigation experience. URIs provide an improved navigation experience that permits navigation to any page in the application, without having to follow a set navigation hierarchy. In addition, it also provides the ability to **navigate backwards** without having to visit all of the pages on the navigation stack.

I have been able to setup my `Shell` file and set my `Route` names. The following code works as expected and navigates me to the appropriate `Page`:

```
private async void NavigateToAbout_Execute()
{
    await (App.Current.MainPage as Shell).GoToAsync("app://Testapp/Test/modal");
}
```

**The Problem:**

Once I have successfully navigated to this `Page`, it seems I have no way of navigating away from the `Page`. In the quote above it states that we should have the ability to navigate backwards (to the previous `Page`) but I can't see any way of achieving this. Has anyone had some experience with this yet? I appreciate it's a pre-release so I may not get a response but any thoughts would be helpful.

Comment: maybe you could use Route to navigation to previous page's url,for example,you route to "app://test/pages/page1" ,then navigate back by route to "app://test/page/pages".

Comment: @LeoZhu-MSFT But it should be as simple as pressing the software back button if there was one available, but there isn't. It appears like a Modal page and theres no way of going back unless I navigated to the route of the previous page I was at

Comment: Yes, you are right. I will do some researching

Comment: I am trying to figure this out now too!

Comment: I was able to achieve it with `await Shell.Current.Navigation.PushAsync(new DetailPage());`. I thought the point was to use GoToAsync so I'm not exactly sure why this method exists if you can't use the back button with routes.

Comment: @Chucky In the end I decided to stay away from version 4 of Xamarin after I saw the amount of bugs that are in progress on their github

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same question. It seems now to be ok. This work for me :

```
await Shell.Current.Navigation.PopAsync();
```

You can also have a look at this variable :

```
Shell.Current.Navigation.NavigationStack
```

It's a list with all the detail pages that were pushed above/onto the pages defined in the shell.
 I've seen that the 0 index in this list is always null. It represents the last page of the shell. The "detail" pages added onto the shell with `shell.Current.GotoAsync("detailpage")` comes from index 1 to n in the `NavigationStack`.